# How to upload multiple images as multiple nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I built a social network website that is like [Instagram](http://instagram.com/) (users can follow each other, upload images and ...) but it focuses on some event. People send us tens of thousands of images every year and we present them on their profile in the website.

Every thing is fine with this website. The only problem is for users who send many images (usually more than 50), It is difficult for them to click on `Create New Content` link for every image and save that image and create new content again. To solve this problem I allow the `images` content type to have unlimited number of image field and used [Multipleupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) to allow users to select multiple files at once.

But every content must have exactly one image, so if a user selects multiple images for a content, we need to have a mechanism to separate every image as a distinct content, we can also share the `Title` of the content among all of them.

The only solution I found so far is to build a module that check for the number of images and create new content for each one on `node save` hook. I would like to know is there any other solution? any module or strategy to handle this requirement?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

as @Gokul N K recommended I installed [Bulk File Nodes](https://www.drupal.org/project/bulk_file_nodes) Module, I also installed [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module. After selecting the Image field in `Bulk Photo Node Settings` vertical tab, This is what I see in `node/add/image`

[image]

and I can't add any image, By clicking on `next` button this page is reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Bulk File Nodes Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bulk_file_nodes)

> Bulk File Nodes allows a user to upload or import many files at once,
>   and have many individual nodes created, one for each file . Where this
>   module significantly differentiates from other modules like Bulk Media
>   Upload is that after uploading/importing the file(s), the user is
>   given the opportunity to edit all of the fields for each node in a
>   single form.
>
> Another form to the right acts as a bulk settings form where each
>   field that has a value is applied to each node's corresponding field,
>   except where the user has overridden the bulk settings form by
>   specifying a value in the field of an individual node.

Comment: Your solution is promising but I encountered a problem. I updated my question, Please check it out.

Comment: I found the problem, I had to copy `plupload` in to `/libraries` folder